# ../ doesn't work (HTML)

Tags: html, directory

EDIT: ../../ works for href links, but doesn't work for accessing stylesheets or js files.

I have a page in a projects folder, that has this in the heading:
 `<li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>`
When I press the link, it tries to redirect me to projects/index.html, instead of the index.html file in the root folder.

Comment: This would be an issue w/ the web server, which you have provided no information about.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have tried two different webservers, the one I am currently using is x10hosting.com free host

Comment: @PrecastDragon x10hosting.com is a web host not a server. it has a website builder which is probably a rich text editor of some kind.(also not a server) look for a file/directory listing and notice where your page with this link is in relation to the index.html page and post the directory paths.

Comment: @Archangel33 Whoops :P The directory paths are like this:
root/index.html and root/projects/webpage.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe your index html in your project will always be the default landing page. It is hard to troubleshoot this without your file structure but have you tried renaming tour your page something different to index.html to see if the behavior continues without the "index" in it.

Answer (score 0):

The path you show in the comments says that webpage.html is down a level from projects folder.

Try `href="../../index.html"`  to move down two levels.

Answer (score 0):

think of it like this a single `../` gets you out of the page; an additional `../` moves you up out of the directory.

With the paths you provided in the comments:

```
/index.html
/projects/webpage.html
```

This is where the links will take you from webpage.html:

```
/index.html      --> /index.html          -- absolute path
../index.html    --> /projects/index.html -- relative path (NOT WHERE YOU WANT TO BE) 
../../index.html --> /index.html          -- relative path
```

you can use either the absolute path or the relative path to link to the index page. I like to use the absolute path to index because my index page is always at the root of my websites. its up to you which you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured this out actually